# System.identityHashCode is equal on String instances

Tags: java, reflection, cloning

because of reasons I am trying to copy/clone instances of objects. And in the case of String i tried something like this:

I do have an object like

```
class Foo{
    private String test;
    //Getters && Setters are generated
}
```

and a copy method like:

```
private static Object copyMemberData(Object originalMemberData) {
    if (originalMemberData == null) {
        return null;
    }

    ...
    if (originalMemberData instanceof String) {
        return String.valueOf(originalMemberData);
    } 
    ...
}
```

which is used like

```
PropertyDescriptor propDesc = new PropertyDescriptor("test", Foo.class);
//Get Data from original object
final Object originalMemberData = propDesc.getReadMethod().invoke(originalFoo);
final Object copiedMemberData = copyMemberData(originalMemberData);
```

And afterwards I tried to compare the result with `System.identityHashCode` to ensure that I am not working on a reference.

```
if (System.identityHashCode(copiedMemberData) == System.identityHashCode(originalMemberData)) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Cloning is buggy!");
}
```

And I am suprised this actually matches and throws me an error. Maybe someone can explain me the reason for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out :-)

The String is the same even if I do compare it with == instead of equals. This is the case because the `toString()` method of the `String.java` class which is used in `String.valueOf(Object obj)` is implemented like:

```
public String toString() {
    return this;
}
```

To successfully copy a String use:

```
return new String(((String)originalMemberData).toCharArray());
```

Comment: Why do you even want to copy a string? `String`s are immutable, so nobody can change the value of the old one.

Comment: It because this is not the only thing I am trying to copy. And as I do not want to create even more if else statements in this part of the coding I am handling each object/type/member the same. Which does lead me to the issue that I have to really "copy" even a String ;-)

Comment: No?. Just use the original reference? And an "easy" way to do what you need would be to serialize and deserialize the graph.

Comment: Serialization is on a lazy initializing object a bad idea ;-) Otherwise it would take some time to create a String from all the db dependencies :-) And yeah I do handle specific types on specific ways. So a general serialization of an object is not working.

Comment: And by the way I wrote the statement to copy a String like that because otherwise Intellij is warning me :-P `new String((String)originalMemberData)` is correct aswell!

Comment: Your explanation makes no sense. You say, you are handling “each object/type/member the same”, but the code you’re showing, is `String` specific. So it isn’t the same as with other members. Besides that, assuming that your initial attempt was fulfilling your requirements of handling all members the same, what’s the problem with the *result* being the same instance? After all, it means that you did already get the right treatment of immutable instances *for free* and replaced your original code with something more complicated, to get an obsolete copy.

Comment: I do copy an object with reflection, and on one hand do use an unspecific implementation to loop any member of the class. On the other hand I need a "clone", method which does the copy for each type in specific. And in this case it's a String. Afterwards each copied object will be checked if it's really copied because of call by reference stuff, except it's a primitive. And yeah it may be right that a String is immutable and would fulfill my needs by now. Until some excellent guy of Oracle comes up with the idea to change this :D And yeah it might by and might not.

Comment: Keep in mind that some types are not only immutable, but also do not support cloning at all, e.g. `enum` types. The Java designers already acknowledged that supporting cloning of immutable types like `String` was a historical mistake. If it were to be designed today, there was no cloning support at all. Likewise, all newer immutable types do not offer such facility. E.g. the objects from `java.time` offer factory methods only, returning objects of an intentionally unspecified identity, which even allows reusing the existing instance you’re trying to clone…